# Excel FORECAST.ETS What method based on?

Tags: forecasting, excel, exponential-smoothing

Excel offers an exponential smoothing function. I currently use Excel 2013. In the [Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORECAST-ETS-function-15389b8b-677e-4fbd-bd95-21d464333f41?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) it says:

> Calculates or predicts a future value based on existing (historical)
>   values by using the AAA version of the Exponential Smoothing (ETS)
>   algorithm

After some research, I found that the ETS (exponential tripple smoothing) is based on the Holt-Winters Method. But again, there are `additive` and `multiplicative` ways of implementing the formulas. As Microsoft does not provide detailed information about its implementation of its functions, **does anyone have further resources or information on what algorithm / formulas, the FORECAST.ETS is based on?** Same goes for the FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT function.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: What is the version of Excel?

Comment: "AAA" is shorthand for *additive* models of residuals ("error"), trend, and seasonality.  See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/7.3.

Comment: What strikes me as strange, is that the (generated) seasonal offsets are always the same. It seems to follow the formula `v(s, i) = seasonBase + seasonalTrend[s] + seasonalOffset[i]`, while ETS-AAA follows `F(t+m) = S(t) + m*b(t) +c(t-L+1+(M-1) mod L)` (wikipedia). Note the `m*b(t)` part. It is incremented by the trend for each increment of `m`. Excel doesn't do this, and increments it for every season. Is Excel even following the ETS-AAA 'spec'?